# How to get this expressionengine query to include results from two tables?

Tags: sql, inner-join, expressionengine

Any one know if this incorrect SQL query is possible using ExpressionEngine Query module?

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_categories WHERE parent_id='{last_segment}'" && exp_category_field_data WHERE field_id_2='on'"}
```

I am trying to use a result from exp_categories and exp_category_field_data where both are true when `parent_id='x' and field_id_2='x'`.

I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    exp_categories c
        LEFT JOIN
    exp_category_field_data d ON c.cat_id = d.cat_id
WHERE
    parent_id = '{last_segment}'
        AND field_id_2 = 'on'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks AllnOne

We got there in the end with this :

{exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_categories a, exp_category_field_data b  WHERE a.parent_id='{last_segment}' AND b.field_id_2='on' AND a.cat_id=b.cat_id"}

Thanks for your help